# How can I convert this sql query using javascript?

Tags: javascript, sql

I want to convert this query1 to query2 using javascript.

query1:

```sql
select min(amount) as minPrice, max(amount) as maxPrice from type_4 where assetId="EvN8cvuGKC2t1PA8ZEsgJth3paenSP4UAd8Z6K14z2P4"
```

query2:

```sql
select min("amount") as minPrice, max("amount") as maxPrice from "type_4" where "assetId"='EvN8cvuGKC2t1PA8ZEsgJth3paenSP4UAd8Z6K14z2P4';
```

Comment: To handle this sort of thing generally you would need to write a SQL parser.  Note that the RHS of the `assetId` assignment probably should be in _single_, not double, quotes, because it is a string literal.  Also, tell us which version of SQL you are using.

Comment: Query 1 is Mysql 8.0.13Query 2 is Sql Sap Hana .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried to build a basic function for conversion.

```js
function convertQuery(query) {
  query = query.replace(/\"/g, '\'')
    .replace(/\)/g, '")')
    .replace(/\(/g, '("')
    .replace(/from /g, 'from "')
    .replace(/\=/, '"=');
  query = query.split(' ');
  var build = [];
  query.forEach(el => {
    if (el[0] === '"')
      build.push(el + '"');
    else if (el.search('=') !== -1)
      build.push('"' + el);
    else build.push(el);

  });

  return build.join(' ');
}

console.log(convertQuery('select min(amount) as minPrice, max(amount) as maxPrice from type_4 where assetId="EvN8cvuGKC2t1PA8ZEsgJth3paenSP4UAd8Z6K14z2P4"'))
```